# Adding Random Fee to Order Total

Tags: magento-enterprise

I am working on a website geared for the South East Asia market. I have been told that many S.E.A. websites will add a randomly generated "fee" of some sort, perhaps equivilant to 1-2 cent USD to the order to either use as a reference number or to make the order totals different to differentiate the order when people are sending in bank wires and such.

The way it was explained to me is that it would be hard to tell what a bank wire is for if there are multiple orders with the same total value. It seems like Groupon Indonesia incorporates something like this under the "Payment Code" name.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Magento? The main thing is that the fee would need to be randomly generated and within a specific currency range.

Answer (score 1):

If you google for "magento surcharge" you will find various modules and code examples that allow you to add surcharges to a Magento order based on a certain criteria, payment method, product attribute etc.

I would modify one of these modules to implement your solution whereby a random surcharge is generated and added to the order.

You would need to have some Magento/PHP development experience to implement this solution as a custom module.

Answer (score 1):

Clone my module in github. Magento Random Payment Fee Method Charge Extension

https://github.com/tobidsn/paymentrandomfee